# WCF service works locally on App Server but can reach it from Web Server

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wsdl

I have WCF service works locally on App Server `http://appserver.org/UserManagementService.svc?wsdl` and `https://localhost/UserManagementService.svc` meaning that it will show me the XML defenition of the WSDL, but can NOT reach `http://appserver.org/UserManagementService.svc?wsdl` or `http://appserver.org/UserManagementService.svc` from Web Server, I also cant reach those address's from my development machine, inside VS or directly in a browser.  I get the error below when I try:

```
There was an error downloading 'https://appserver.org/UserManagementService.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://appserver.org/UserManagementService.svc'.
There was no endpoint listening at https://prod-uibenapps.sces.org/UserManagementService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

This is the web.config for the service application hosting the services in IIS

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WedWiaPortal.SCAL">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <!--<add baseAddress="http://localhost/usermanagementservice"/>-->
            <add baseAddress="http://prod-uibenapps.sces.org/UserManagementService.svc"></add>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="WedWiaPortal.SCAL.IUserManagementService" />
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Thank you in advance for any help, have been banging my head a couple of days.

Comment: Well, the IIS is responding with "I cannot find that thing on the URL your referencing" - so looks to me like an IIS issue more than an actual web service issue.

Im seeing you referencing alot of http and not https - but in your error - Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: -"https:..."

Comment: I am thinking it is an IIS issue also, but I have never had this issue before so i wasnt sure.  No matter if i use http or https from the remote server i get the same response I will contact the IIS guys and see if I need to assign a specific IP address.